# Styling <select> multiple Attribute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just found out about `multiple` attribute of a `select` tag. I implemented it in my project but it doesn't look good and I have to hold ctrl to choose more than one, which is kind of annoying. I wanted to know if there is any way to style it to make it look better because the main goal is **choosing one or more words out of five**.

[image: Here is a preview of what i have]

And the code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-form-label">Select some options</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="aluno" multiple>
          <option selected="true" disabled>Click to select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>Option 3</option>
          <option>Option 4</option>
          <option>Option 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Select2](https://select2.org/)?

Comment: Holding ctrl to select more than one is a well known UI/UX element that most ppl who need to select more than one thing knows

Comment: _"the main goal is choosing one or more words out of five."_ - in that case, I might rather go with five checkboxes + labels to begin with ...

Comment: "Look better" isn't a specific problem statement. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mrplungjan mentioned - "Holding ctrl to select more than one is a well-known UI/UX element that most ppl who need to select more than one thing know."

Essentially, most people looking to select multiple options out of a select menu should be familiar with the ctrl function, to select multiple. This is why it is a default with the `select` and `option` elements.

However, you can write a script to combat this, and get the output you desire. Check out this example using jQuery.

```js
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var originalScrollTop = $(this).parent().scrollTop();
    console.log(originalScrollTop);
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
    var self = this;
    $(this).parent().focus();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).parent().scrollTop(originalScrollTop);
    }, 0);
    
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-form-label">Select some options</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="aluno" multiple>
          <option selected="true" disabled>Click to select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>Option 3</option>
          <option>Option 4</option>
          <option>Option 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element) for more information on styling select and option elements. It may be easiest to apply a Bootstrap library.

Comment: The question is about styling, not behavior. Also, if this is a duplicate answer (as suggested by the use of a very old jQuery version), it should be flagged for closure, not repeated.